# Something is of/in the order of

Tags: prepositions

What is the right preposition in

> The human's weight is (of/in) the order of 10^2 kg.

Are both correct, or do they have different meanings? I found both in the internet and I found many discussions on this question without a solution. I guess SX is ideal to find a short solution.

Comment: I would say it is *on* the order of ...

Comment: The idiom is **on** _the order_. Occasionally one sees _of the order_ in discussions of magnitude, but that's a very specialized usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the UK, the idiom is *of the order of* (at least, in the example quoted, "of the order of 100kg").

*In [the] order of* specifies a sequence; and *on the order of* specifies who made an edict.

[ODO entry](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/order?q=of+the+order+of#order__58):

> *of the order of*: approximately; having the order of magnitude specified by...

Comment: And, writing *10^2 kg* or *10² kg* is unusual to point of being highly irregular.

Answer (score 5):

The vast majority of these citations from Google Books will probably all match OP's context...

> ...distance is **of** the order of... [6670 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22distance%20is%20of%20the%20order%20of%22&oq=%22distance%20is%20of%20the%20order%20of%22&gs_l=serp.3...15229.18166.1.18676.9.9.0.0.0.0.105.608.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.MvswfHbCfYY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.d2k&fp=cc60941f39a1f1cf&bpcl=39967673&biw=1271&bih=829)
>
> ...distance is **in** the order of... [1050 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22distance%20is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&oq=%22distance%20is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&gs_l=serp.3...11147.13699.2.14082.4.4.0.0.0.0.166.385.3j1.4.0...0.0...1c.1.KMgIdThf8Hk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.d2k&fp=cc60941f39a1f1cf&bpcl=39967673&biw=1271&bih=829)
>
> ...distance is **on** the order of... [907 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is%20in%20the%20order%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22distance%20is%20on%20the%20order%20of%22&oq=%22distance%20is%20on%20the%20order%20of%22&gs_l=serp.3...19683.20099.3.20336.2.2.0.0.0.0.60.120.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.BEIuhU25jLk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.d2k&fp=cc60941f39a1f1cf&bpcl=39967673&biw=1271&bih=829)

Whilst I don't see clear-cut reasons for saying any particular preposition is either "right" or "wrong", I personally prefer **in**. The repetition of **of** slightly turns me off the first alternative, and I simply don't come across **on** very often, so it seems a little "strange" to my ear.

I would also just say the ratios implied by figures are only an approximate guide to actual usage. The corresponding figures for *"**weight**"* are **of**:2680, **in**:1150 **on**:396. But the basic message is *they're all used reasonably often, but **of** is the most common form*.

Comment: 'Of the order' likely gets a big boost in google books via the use of 'order' in taxonomy:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(biology)

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger: That would seem vanishingly unlikely, bearing in mind that I specifically preceded the expressions by *distance* and *weight* in my searches. I suppose somebody could have written something like *"The monarch butterfly, which migrates an incredible distance, is in the order of Lepidoptera"*. But that ain't gonna skew the usage figures significantly.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Ngram Viewer, as a tool aiming at quantitative results, is more suitable than Google Books. It shows the usage versus time. The [result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=distance+of+the+order+of%2Cdistance+in+the+order+of%2Cdistance+on+the+order+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdistance%20of%20the%20order%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdistance%20in%20the%20order%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdistance%20on%20the%20order%20of%3B%2Cc0) is much more pronounced in favour of "of", especially before 1950 (before US contribution to technical literature became dominant), and places "on" ahead of "in" (compare comments to the question).