# Is this ellipsis of the head noun in “be of” constructions?

Tags: prepositions, ellipses

I was asked about a sentence from *The Economist* and I found it difficult to explain the usage of *of* in it:

> The most alarming scenario **is of rogue AI turning evil**, as seen in countless sci-fi films.

At first, I've found several other sentences from corpora that I believed to have a similar usage, which all have *be of* with an -ing participle.

> One of my favorite memories of mathematics **is of doing modules in elementary school**.
>
> The first impression she gave **was of being young and petit**—too much of both for police work.
>
> Her life seems to depend on it, and her daily experience **is of doing battle to maintain that control**.
>
> The risk for Francis, as with his predecessor, **is of being more admired than adhered to**.

It seems that in these sentences, *be of* doesn't mean "possess intrinsically; give rise to", as in *be of great value* or *be of interest*. Instead, the head nouns of the subject can be supplemented between *be* and *of*, and they all seem to be abstract nouns that are related to some kind of "scene".

> The most alarming **scenario** is (the scenario) of rogue AI turning evil, as seen in countless sci-fi films.
>
> One of my favorite **memories** of mathematics is (the memory) of doing modules in elementary school.

I've also found [the sentence discussed here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71277/meaning-and-usage-of-be-of) and [the second example discussed here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/594547/what-does-be-of-mean), which seem to have similar constructions. They don't fit all the patterns above, but we can also add a noun from the subject before *of* to "complete" them.

> The theologian Basil the Great reported that the dominant view of **hell** among the believers he knew was (a hell) of a limited, “purgatorial” suffering.
>
> By 1940, the pilot Jacqueline Cochran held seventeen official national and international speed records, earned at a time when aviation was still so new that many of the **planes** she flew were (planes) of dangerously experimental design.

Therefore, I think this might be some sort of ellipsis or deletion, but after checking *OED* and several reference grammars I haven't found a satisfactory explanation. My main questions are

1. Is this a type of ellipsis? Is there a name for the usage/phenomenon? Does it happen predominantly in formal texts?
2. Will the sentence mean differently if the *of* is removed in the original sentences? (For example, how is *The most alarming scenario is rogue AI turning evil* different from *The most alarming scenario is of rogue AI turning evil*?) How can I tell whether I need an *of* in this position?

Comment: Compare https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541829/the-usage-of-is-of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137863/what-is-meaning-of-is-of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94451/something-is-of-in-the-order-of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/alternatives-to-he-is-of-the-opinion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning and usage of “be of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71277/meaning-and-usage-of-be-of): '... many of the planes she flew were of dangerously experimental design' for '... many of the planes she flew were [planes [that were]] of dangerously experimental design'. 'This phenomenon is a headless relative clause that happens to have a prepositional phrase.' (@J Lawler)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had a link to that discussion in my question. I do think the sentence has a similar usage but I'd like to know more about it. Lawler said it's a result of deletion, but why is such a deletion possible? According to Quirk et al.'s _A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language_ (p. 904), it's impossible to have ellipsis of every part of a noun phrase except for postmodifiers, but here the head noun is deleted with only an of-phrase left.

Comment: Yes. Note however that Quirk's sentences are different from yours, mainly comparative (*'The Strait of Gibraltar is narrower than of Dover'). Here, [be (is/are/was ...) of] can be replaced by a colon (though admittedly the one in the previous thread then sounds stodgy).

Comment: In all those cases, you have an elliptical anaphoric *that*: *The most alarming scenario is [that] of rogue AI turning evil... One of my favorite memories of mathematics is [that] of doing modules... The first impression she gave was [that] of being young... Her life seems to depend on it, and her daily experience is [that] of doing battle... The risk for Francis, as with his predecessor, is [that] of being more admired...*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What do you mean by "can be replaced by a colon"? Isn't that going to make the sentence a sentence fragment? And in my thread I stated that I'm trying to figure out (1) why such a deletion is possible, (2) how "be of (doing) sth" is different from "be (doing) sth", neither of which has been answered in the linked thread.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thank you so much! So my assumption about ellipsis was reasonable. I'd still like to know how the meaning is going to be different from the original if we simply remove the _of_ (e.g., _The most alarming scenario is rogue AI turning evil_), since I assume that the _of_ in these cases expresses an appositive meaning. Also, could you please recommend some articles or book chapters on the ellipsis of anaphoric _that_?

Comment: Sentence fragments are not unacceptable to many modern writers. / Explanation probably lost in the midst of time. / I'd say deleting the 'of' makes negligible if any difference to the meaning.

Comment: In some cases, when you remove the *of*, you run a slight risk of a misread, along the lines of: *My memory is doing modules... The impression is being young... Her experience is doing battle...*

Comment: @Tinfoil Yes; as deletions multiply, so do possible alternative readings. I bet you're still working on a string posing a more realistically problematic ambiguity. _The memory of the crash victim was [of] coming back weeks ago_. Here, of course, 'memory' is polysemic.